# Error when Checking Email Availability for Gmail Account Creation using Google Workspace Admin Directory API

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a Gmail account using the Google Workspace Admin Directory API in my C# application. I've followed all the necessary steps outlined in the documentation, but I'm facing an issue and need some assistance.

Error:
When I attempt to check the availability of an email address, I encounter the following error message:
Error checking email availability: The service admin has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Not Authorized to access this resource/api

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace himmish_net_manage
{
    public partial class createEmailAccount : Window
    {
        public createEmailAccount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // string jsonFileName = "himish-net-393302-f0067b03b10e.json";
            //  string jsonCredentialsPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, jsonFileName);
            string jsonCredentialsPath = "C:\\Users\\jbjfn\\source\\repos\\himmish-net-manage\\himmish-net-manage\\himish-net-393302-f0067b03b10e.json";

            string adminUser = "{myEmailAddress}@gmail.com"; // Admin user email                       /// i will put my real on 

            User newUser = new User
            {
                PrimaryEmail = EmailTextBox.Text,
                Name = new UserName { GivenName = FirstNameTextBox.Text, FamilyName = LastNameTextBox.Text },
                Password = PasswordBox.Text,
            };

            // Check if the email address is available
            if (IsEmailAvailable(newUser.PrimaryEmail, jsonCredentialsPath, adminUser))
            {
                // Create the user
                CreateUser(newUser, jsonCredentialsPath);
            }
            else
            {
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "Email address is not available.";
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            if (textBox.Text == textBox.Tag.ToString())
            {
                textBox.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                textBox.Text = textBox.Tag.ToString();
            }
        }


        ///////////
        ///
        static bool IsEmailAvailable(string email, string jsonCredentialsPath, string adminUser)
        {
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonCredentialsPath)
                .CreateScoped(DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser);

            var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Google Workspace User Creation"
            });

            try
            {
                var request = service.Users.Get(email);
                var user = request.Execute();
                return false; // User already exists
            }
            catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
            {
                if (e.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    return true; // User does not exist
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error checking email availability: " + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

                    Console.WriteLine("Error checking email availability: " + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        static void CreateUser(User newUser, string jsonCredentialsPath)
        {
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonCredentialsPath)
                .CreateScoped(DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser);



            var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Google Workspace User Creation"
            });

            try
            {
                var request = service.Users.Insert(newUser);
                var createdUser = request.Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("User created successfully: " + createdUser.PrimaryEmail);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error creating user: " + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

                Console.WriteLine("Error creating user: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Steps Taken:

Created a Service Account and obtained the JSON key file.
Enabled the required APIs and granted the "Service Account Token Creator" role.
Delegated domain-wide authority in Google Workspace Admin Console.
Authorized the service account and obtained the JSON key file.
Verified the correct path to JSON key file in code (jsonCredentialsPath).
Confirmed usage of correct API scope (DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser).
Ensured API requests include the necessary authorization header.
Verified the required permissions and roles are granted.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1.Verified correct service account email and domain-wide authority setup.

2.Checked accuracy of JSON key file path.

3.Confirmed correct API scope usage.

4.Refreshed access tokens as needed.

5.Enabled necessary APIs in Google Cloud Console.

6.Passed access token in authorization header.

7.Debugged and logged error response from API request.

8.Tried temporarily granting additional permissions to service account.

Despite meticulously following all the steps and thorough troubleshooting, I'm still facing the "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" error. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.